# Does keras include a was to turn a classifier's prediction into a classification?

Tags: categorical-encoding, keras

I have a model where the output is a one-hot encoding of 6 classes, meaning y_train is of the shape (1000,6)

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=10)
```

Now, I want to give the model an input and get some classifications out. This

```
y_hat_train = model.predict_on_batch(X_test)
```

outputs the raw values, like
[0.2,0.1,0.9,0.5,0.3,0.3]
not the classification.
Is there a function in Keras (or any other python library) to automatically turn this into
[0,0,1,0,0,0]
?

Answer (score 1):

Would it not be simplest to round the values to the nearest integer:

```
y_hat_class = [round(x) for x in y_hat_train]
```

Are you sure that's what you want to do though? At the moment you have predictions and if you dichotomise these to 0 or 1 you are throwing away information. For instance, your 0.1 and 0.5 both get rounded down to 0, but the model is in some sense more confident about the 0.1 than the 0.5. You will lose this nuance by classifying.

This is related to [proper scoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoring_rule#Expected_loss) metrics and whether [accuracy](https://www.fharrell.com/post/class-damage/) and related measures are the most suitable way to assess performance.

Comment: The trouble with this approach is that a vector like $(0.3, 0.4, 0.3)$ gets rounded to $(0,0,0)$, but +1 for the mention of proper scoring rules and Frank Harrell’s blog.